# SQL Server CTE with multiple delete statements

Tags: common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

I have a CTE:

```
;WITH DeleteTarget AS
(
    ....
)
```

How do I use this CTE for two delete statements - maybe like:

```
DELETE FROM [TableA]
WHERE ColumnA IN (SELECT Id FROM DeleteTarget)

DELETE FROM [TableB]
WHERE ColumnB IN (SELECT Name FROM DeleteTarget)
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot - a CTE only exists for **the one, next statement**.

If you need this information that the CTE provides more than once, you need to:

- store the result set into a table variable or temp table
- then execute your multiple statements using that table variable / temp table